# Can a ready action be a combination of actions?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I know that [readying an action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Ready) is a standard action, meaning you can do some things before you ready an action, just not any standard actions.

However, can you ready a few actions together?

Can you, for example, ready both a move and a standard action?  I think not since the line reads as follows;

> You can ready a standard action, a move action, a swift action, or a free action.

I would like confirmation that I'm interpreting this correctly though.

Also, can you ready a standard or move action AND a free action?  Like readying a weapon drop and a move action.

Seems like that would be reasonable house rule but I'm looking for a RAW answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### You can only ready one action

You certainly can't ready a standard *and* a move action.  The rules are very specific that you ready *an* action.

### Free actions are free!

What about adding a free action?  Well:

> You can perform one or more free actions while taking another action normally.

You can't literally ready both, but it seems like there's nothing preventing you from taking a free action along with your later action.  Free actions accompany another of your actions; they don't seem to *necessarily* have to occur on your turn.

Keep in mind that if you couldn't use a free action along with your readied action, you wouldn't be able to draw ammunition or prepare spell components.  Generally the rules seem to assume that if you're performing one action, a free action can come along for, well, *free*.

### Other actions

If you can take a free action, you can take a swift action:

> You can take a swift action anytime you would normally be allowed to take a free action.

Finally, the rules explicitly state that a five-foot step ("not an action") is ok:

> You can take a 5-foot step as part of your readied action, but only if you don't otherwise move any distance during the round.

### What the rules *also* say

A DM can explicitly limit your free actions, if they feel it to be reasonable.  So personally, I'd allow you to drop a weapon and then move, but I might not allow you to case a quickened spell along with a readied action for spellcasting.

Comment: So, in your view, a creature **needs to** or **need not** be fully prepared beforehand for an action to ready that action? That is, must an archer have *already* readied her ammunition *before* declaring her action and trigger as *I take a standard action to make a standard attack if at any creature that rounds the corner*?

Answer (score 7):

### No.

The ready action clearly indicates that a *single* action is readied.

> **Ready**
>
> The ready action lets you prepare to take *an* action later, after your turn is over but before your next one has begun. Readying is a standard action.
>
> **Readying an Action**
>
> You can ready *a* standard action, *a* move action, *a* swift action, or *a* free action.

Emphasis mine.